# Skip workflow confirmation page

Tags: 2010, task-list

I'm trying to add a "Mark Complete" option for the task list (I've noticed 2013 has it by default but 2010 does not). I made a workflow that sets the appropriate values on the task, added it to the list of Custom Actions in the List Item Menu, and it works. However, whenever I click it, SharePoint prompts me to confirm that I want to begin the workflow (`To start the workflow, use the submit button in the form below.`), which is a bit overkill for something as simple as this.

Is there a way to have SharePoint skip the confirmation page? If not, should I give up on trying to solve this with workflows and write some code instead?

Edit: Here's a more detailed description of the process. Some user makes a task. The user then proceeds to work on the task, which may take hours, days, or months. In the meantime, the user will likely update the task with new information. Once the task is complete, the user clicks the "mark as complete" button, which begins the SharePoint workflow. Alternatively, the user perform the same operations as the workflow by manually editing the task (setting Status to "Complete", Progress to 100% and Work Remaining to 0). Using the "mark as complete" button is supposed to be a shortcut for setting those three values. Unfortunately, with 3 clicks and 2 pageloads, it is not much of a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Could enable automatic start on item change in workflow settings for a 'Mark Complete' workflow?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That definitely gets rid of the confirmation page, but it defeats the point because editing a task automatically begins the workflow.

Comment: So the workflow sets the values, and after the values are set, the task is complete?  Maybe I should have said 'Enable automatic start on item CREATION'.  That way when the fields are set, it completes? (If Current Item:Value is not empty), etc.  Hope you find an answer for this.

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't being very clear initially. I edited the question with more information.

Comment: Understood.  I completely agree with "it is not much of a shortcut"!  I'd like to know to answer to this as well.  I have been using InfoPath forms and just populating 'STATUS' fields with button clicks to determine where it's at in the process, and have just started modifying an Approval workflow (so I'm no expert) to attempt to do things simply(from the users point of view).

Comment: Alright I may see how involved writing something with C# is. If I get it working, I'll open source it and let you know.